# How to save sent email with attachment

Tags: python, email, email-attachments

I wrote an agent to send emails with smtp server.
All is ok about sending, but I would like to save an `.eml` file that contains not only the body, but also all the attachments.

I tried several ways without lucky.

This is my code (please don't look at the missing error checks).
Also some part of the code is missing for simplicity.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEBase, MIMEMultipart
from email import encoders, message, utils, generator , message_from_bytes,message_from_string

def _attachment(filename,file_path=None):
    fp_filename = ''
    if file_path is not None:
        fp_filename = file_path+'/'+filename
    else:
        fp_filename = self.attachdir+'/'+filename
    fd = open(fp_filename, 'rb')
    mimetype, mimeencoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    if mimeencoding or (mimetype is None):
        mimetype = 'application/octet-stream'
    maintype, subtype = mimetype.split('/')
    if maintype == 'text':
        retval = MIMEText(fd.read(), _subtype=subtype)
    else:
        retval = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
        retval.set_payload(fd.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(retval)
    retval.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
            filename = filename)
    fd.close()
    return retval


# ...
# prepare msg body
msg_content = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
  span.bold {font-weight: bold;}
  table.noborder {border: 0px; padding: 8px;}
  th {text-align: left;}
</style>
 </head>
<body>
<p>
  Hello From Me :-)
</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

#create message obgject
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(MIMEText(msg_content, 'html', 'utf-8'))

msg['From'] = mfrom
msg['To'] = recipient
msg['Reply-to'] = reply
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['Date'] = utils.formatdate(localtime = 1)

msg.attach(_attachment(filename='samplefile.pdf',file_path='./'))

# no error check reported in this code sample
conn = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtpserver,smtpport)
conn.login(smtplogin, smtppass)
conn.sendmail(e.mfrom, [comm.destinatario], msg.as_string())
conn.quit()

with open('file_1.eml', 'w') as f:
    gen = generator.Generator(f)
    gen.flatten(msg)
                        

 msg_b = message_from_string(msg.as_string())
 with open('file_2.eml', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(bytes(msg_b))
 
 with open('file_3.eml', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(msg.as_bytes())
```

In every file (1,2,3) I can see only the email body: no attachment!

Can you help me?

Comment: when I run your code then I get 3 files with attachment. Better create minimal working code which makes problem - and then we can test it and see problem. At this moment your code is OK for me.

Comment: Thank you @furas. maybe it is a visualization problem. when I open the eml file with outlook I can't see the attachment. but when I go to see the received email, on Webmail, I can see the attachment. I also tried to upload the mail in Sent Items, and, viewing from webmail, it's OK, this is a strange outlook behavior.

Answer (score 3):

*Moved from an edit to the question by the OP to an answer.*

Use `email.message.EmailMessage`, as reported in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

The old method created some issues in viewing attachments for some users.

This is the working code:

```py
import mimetypes
import smtplib
from email import utils
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.policy import SMTP

import html2text

# prepare msg body
msg_content = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
  span.bold {font-weight: bold;}
  table.noborder {border: 0px; padding: 8px;}
  th {text-align: left;}
</style>
 </head>
<body>
<p>
  Hello From Me :-)
</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
mfrom = 'addremail@example.com'
mto = 'recipient@example.com'
file_to_attach = 'testfile.PDF'
subject = 'test attachment'
smtp_server = 'localhost' 

# create message object
msg = EmailMessage()

msg['From'] = mfrom
msg['To'] = mto
# msg['Reply-to'] = reply
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['Date'] = utils.formatdate(localtime = 1)
# generate text version
ht = html2text.HTML2Text()
ht.ignore_links = False
# Add Text Version
msg.set_content(ht.handle(msg_content))
# Add HTML Version
msg.add_alternative(msg_content, subtype='html')
# Manage Attachment
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file_to_attach)
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
    # No guess could be made, or the file is encoded (compressed), so
    # use a generic bag-of-bits type.
    ctype = 'application/octet-stream'
maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
with open(file_to_attach, 'rb') as fp:
    # add attachment
    msg.add_attachment(fp.read(),
                       maintype=maintype,
                       subtype=subtype,
                       filename=file_to_attach)


# store the message
with open('mail_out.eml', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(msg.as_bytes(policy=SMTP))

# send the message
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server) as s:
    # set debug if needed
    s.set_debuglevel(1)
    # send
    s.send_message(msg)
```